Azure Functions - High Memory Consumption and Duplicate Blob Uploads
I'm encountering two main issues with my Azure Functions setup, and I'm seeking guidance on how to address them effectively.
High Memory Consumption:
I have an Azure Functions application with an orchestrator function triggered by a timer.It calls activity function to send report via email, which involves creating a CSV file and uploading it to Azure Blob Storage.The problem I'm facing is that the memory consumption seems to be high, especially when passing data to the memory stream for CSV creation. This is a concern, particularly when dealing with large datasets. How can I optimize my code to reduce memory usage while still achieving the desired functionality?
Duplicate Blob Uploads and Emails:
Additionally, I've observed instances where Multiple times data is upload into the blob storage, resulting in multiple emails being sent for same orchestrator.
Code Sample:


[Function("SendDataEmail")]
 public async Task<bool> SendDataEmail([ActivityTrigger] List<Data> data)
 {
       if (data == null)
       {
           //logs
           return false;
       }

       var storageConnectionString = //storageConnectionString;
       var reportRootFolder = reportRootFolder;
       var containerName = //containerName;

       var containerClient = new BlobContainerClient(storageConnectionString, containerName);

       var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient($"DataSummary_{DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy_hhmmss")}.csv");

       var isUploaded = await WriteDataAndUploadToBlob(data, blobClient);

       if (!isUploaded)
       {
           //logs
           return false;
       }

       Uri sasUri = new Uri("about:blank");

       var sasCreated = CreateSASForBlob(blobClient, out sasUri);

       if (!sasCreated)
       {
          //logs
           return false;
       }

       var subject = //subject;
       var content = //content;
       var maild=//getmail ids
       
       await SendEmail(subject, content, maild);

       return true;
   } 
   
private async Task<bool> WriteDataAndUploadToBlob(List<Data> data, BlobClient blobClient)
  {
      try
      {
          using (var writer = new StreamWriter(new MemoryStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
          {
              await writer.WriteLineAsync(@"Id,Type");

              foreach (var item in data)
              {
                  var line = $"";                                            
                                         
                  line = $"{item.Id},{item.Type}";
                  await writer.WriteLineAsync(line);
              }
              await writer.FlushAsync();
              writer.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
              var ret = await blobClient.UploadAsync(writer.BaseStream, new BlobHttpHeaders { ContentType = "text/csv", ContentEncoding = "Encoding.UTF8" });
              return ret.GetRawResponse().Status == (int)HttpStatusCode.Created; 
            }
        }
              catch (Exception ex){
              }
              return true; 
    }

1-The problem I'm facing is that the memory consumption seems to be high, especially when passing data to the memory stream for CSV creation. This is a concern, particularly when dealing with large datasets.
2-Multiple times data uploaded to the blob storage,resulting in multiple emails being sent within same time.
Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve these issues would be greatly appreciated.

Could you please share the other relevant parts of the code, such as the Orchestrator itself?

I'm going to address the memory issue only here. Instead of using a memory stream open the Blob and write directly to it.
private async Task<bool> WriteDataAndUploadToBlob(List<Data> data, BlobClient blobClient)
{
    var exists = await blobClient.ExistsAsync();
    if (exists)
        return false; // I assume if the file exists you do not want to upload anything? If not remove this.

    var options = new BlobOpenWriteOptions()
    {
        HttpHeaders = new BlobHttpHeaders { ContentType = "text/csv", ContentEncoding = "utf-8" }
    };

    await using var targetStream = await blobClient.OpenWriteAsync(overwrite: true, options);
    await using var writer = new StreamWriter(targetStream, Encoding.UTF8);
    await writer.WriteLineAsync(@"Id,Type");

    foreach (var item in data)
    {
        await writer.WriteLineAsync($"{item.Id},{item.Type}");
    }
    await writer.FlushAsync();
    return true;
}

